# Getting an Angel Knight in Tactics Ogre

Tags: tactics-ogre

This is specific to the PS1/SNES version.

I have been trying to get a generic character to turn into an angel knight by raising her stats up to exceed the listed thresholds [here](http://luct.tacticsogre.com/special.html). She has been trained mostly as a Valkyrie, is lawful, and has gotten many kills. I worry that there is an undocumented requirement to NOT have killed many foes. I have tried killing her myself as well as letting enemies kill her, but I always end up with nothing more than a dead character.

In the past I have had my priest(ess) die and have her return as an angel knight before I could load my game.  (This was always cause to load because a priest class makes for a poor front-line fighter, and I lost my revivify spell.)

What am I doing wrong?  What are the real requirements to getting an angel knight without recruiting one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "undocumented" requirement to not kill foes.  The only tricky part is there is a percent chance of succeeding in getting an Angel Knight once you meet the requirements.  After trying (dying) with the right woman a few times, she turned into an Angel Knight.